# Tensorflow -How to add embedding to saver

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I train a model with TF and have two files, `myModel.py` and `train_model.py`. For that, I use the following code (train_model.py):

```
...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    my_model = MyModel(placeholders, learning_rate, ...) # builds the graph
    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
    config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(save_path, sess.graph)
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        sess.run([model.opt_op, model.loss, model.accuracy, merged],
                 feed_dict=feed_dict)
        ...
    model.save(path, sess=sess)
```

The model itself implements save and load functions like this (myModel.py):

```
class MyModel:
    self.vars = None
    self.activations = None
    self.build() # builds the graph and fills self.vars & self.activations
    ...

    def save(self, path, sess):
        saver = tf.train.Saver(self.vars)
        saver.save(sess, path)

    def load(self, path, sess):
        saver = tf.train.Saver(self.vars)
        saver.restore(sess, path)
```

This is working well so far as that I can save and load my models and do some calculations there.
However, I now want to visualize the activation at each layer using PCA/TSNE in Tensorboard.

**Here's my question:**

I have to add the embedding in the train_model.py because I want to add it after training. On the other hand, I have to save the embedding variables obtained via:

```
act = output.eval(feed_dict=d, session=sess)
embedding_var = tf.Variable(act, name='activation_layer_{}'.format(i))
```

using my `model.save()` function.
How can I either add variables to the session or save another checkpoint to the same directory?

What is the best way to save the variables? Would you use another checkpoint that only contains the embeddings?

Thanks for your help,

Roman